# how to set a default value for a column in cxGrid?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, tcxgrid, quantumgrid

How to set a default value for a boolean column in cxGrid? I mean i would like that by default all new rows have the value "False" for my boolean column

Comment: Assuming you are displaying data from a dataset, the way to do this is to set the corresponding datafield's value to False in the dataset's OnNewRecord event.  Btw, it was a pity you deleted your ShowEndEllipsis q - interesting and rather challenging (to me) q.

Comment: @MartynA ooh sorry for the ShowEndEllipsis question :( I found the solution, it's was simply to set OptionBehavior.CellHints to true, and I was thinking that my question will be soon downvoted this why I deleted it :( sorry next time I will not delete anymore !

Comment: Don't worry about the ShowEndEllipsis q, and I'm glad you solved it.  I know exactly what you mean about downvotes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a data grid (containing e.g. a cxGridDBTableView), you should set any defaults in the dataset's OnNewRecord event, like this

```
procedure TForm1.ClientDataSet1NewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  Field : TField;
  i : Integer;
begin
  // set all Boolean data fields to False
  for i := 0 to DataSet.FieldCount - 1 do begin
    Field := DataSet.Fields[i];
    if (Field.DataType = ftBoolean) and (Field.FieldKind = fkData) then
    // the test on Field.FieldKind is to avoid disturbing any fkCalculated or fkInternalCalc fields
      Field.AsBoolean := False;
  end;
end;
```

If you do that (or set any other field values in the OnNewRecord event), the values will automatically be transferred to the cxGrid.

**Update** The following shows how to set an initial False value for a boolean column of an
unbound cxGridTableView.  Note: The code creates the TableView so there is no need
to add it or a cxGrid to the form.

```
    // form fields (of Form1)
    cxGrid1 : TcxGrid;
    cxLevel : TcxGridLevel;
    TableView : TcxGridTableView;
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3 : TcxGridColumn;
  end;

 [...]
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  cxGrid1 := TcxGrid.Create(Self);
  cxGrid1.Parent := Self;

  cxLevel := cxGrid1.Levels.Add;
  cxLevel.Name := 'Firstlevel';

  TableView := TcxGridTableView.Create(Self);
  TableView := cxGrid1.CreateView(TcxGridTableView) as TcxGridTableView;
  TableView.Name := 'ATableView';
  TableView.Navigator.Visible := True;

  Col1 := TableView.CreateColumn;
  Col1.DataBinding.ValueType := 'Integer';
  Col1.Caption := 'RowID';

  Col2 := TableView.CreateColumn;
  Col2.DataBinding.ValueType := 'String';
  Col2.Caption := 'RowName';

  Col3 := TableView.CreateColumn;
  Col3.DataBinding.ValueType := 'Boolean';
  Col3.Caption := 'RowChecked';

  cxLevel.GridView := TableView;

  TableView.DataController.OnNewRecord := cxGridTableViewDataControllerNewRecord;
end;

procedure TForm1.cxGridTableViewDataControllerNewRecord(
  ADataController: TcxCustomDataController; ARecordIndex: Integer);
begin
 Caption := IntToStr(ARecordIndex);
  ADataController.Values[ARecordIndex, 2] := False;  // The 2 is the index of Col3
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Martyn, in fact it's not a DBTableView but just a tableView. I would like that all my boolean column have a false value by default instead of a null (gray) value

Comment: See update for how to deal with a plain cxGridTableView.

Comment: Well, you could probably guess that I'm not too familiar with working with unbound grids and you'll notice that the code always adds the new row at the top of the TableView.  The next thing I need to do is to work out how to add the new row at the end (or following some other order).

Comment: it's perfect for me, cxGridTableViewDataControllerNewRecord point me in the good direction, work fine now :)